# How to unit test with data assets C++ Unreal Engine

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I am adding some unit tests to my C++ plugin for Unreal Engine.
I am currently using the [Automation System](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.2/en-US/automation-system-in-unreal-engine/) for that.
I already have working unit tests for the structs and some simple UObjects.

However I am stumbling on a case I don't really know how to handle correctly.
I have an UObject (say `UEntity`) which is instantiated at runtime and is setup with a UDataAsset (say `UEntityData`) that the designers can create in the editor to fill some data inside.
The `UEntityData` contains an array and the `UEntity` access it for some behavior.

My problem here is: How can I provide the `UEntityData` to the `UEntity` in the unit test?

I have some solutions in mind but since I can't find anything on the Internet relating this case I don't know the best approach.

- I could maybe create the data assets with `NewObject<>()` inside the unit test and filling its members before providing them to the `UEntity` instances. (I don't know if it's correct behaviour to use `NewObject<>()` with `UDataAsset` classes, and also I am wondering if it's going beyond the unit testing since I'm relying on some other class constructor and accessors).
- I could create some data asset files in the editor and loading them in the unit tests, however I think it's not a reliable way because the assets are outside the unit tests environment (maybe I'm wrong with this feeling).
- I could create another way to mock up those data assets without using the `UEntityData` class but I'm feeling that this is breaking the purpose of the unit test since it is not really testing the real behavior and cumbersome to duplicate the members and functions between the data assets and the non-data asset mocks. (maybe I'm wrong also here)

So I'm asking here if anybody can lead me to the best way to deal with data assets in unit tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creatinig `UDataAsset`s using templated `UObject` macros such as `NewObject`, `NewNamedObject`, `ConstructObject` is totally fine, and seems like the best approach, for reasons you have noted: indeed, it is best to keep all tests self-contained and not rely on external assets such as ones created in Editor. It also good practice to use the exact classes you will use for the real-world use case.

Data Asset can be treated as plain `UObject` in code, meaning it is supported by `UPROPERTY`, can have/be `Outer` for other objects, rely on reference-based garbage collection, etc. All properties of the Data Asset can safely be assigned/changed in code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, do you mean `NewObject` will **not** do extra things (eg. creating a file) with `UDataAsset` compared to a simple `UObject`?

Comment: What file do you mean? If you create an object that way, it's "transient", meaning in-memory and not linked to a package like a on-disk .uasset file. It should be possible to serialize it and save it disk if needed, but that's a whole other task that I'm not very knowledgeable about. In terms of the constructor, since `UObject`s don't use constructors with parameters, and any kind of initialization like setting member variable values is done separately, nothing should be different.

Comment: I've been able to test today and you're right, thank you!